# Where has all my drive space gone?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I selected all folders, right-clicked and picked Properties.  It shows me all files and they total up to 45.7 GB.

[image]

But then I look at My Computer and see that I should have 74.4 GB:
[image]

Where has all my space gone?

P.S.  As you can see from my first screenshot that I turned on every conceivable option to show everything, but here is the Options dialog.

[image]

Comment: You can't just do properties like this is what my other comment should have said...

Comment: The linked answer does not actually answer my question since it's completely different.  I'll make another question to clarify.

Comment: You want to know where all your space went... How is it different....

Answer (score 0):

There is a small program called  Treesize Free at http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/
that will show you exactly where space is being used. Easy to use and very useful.